# Are UPDATE and DELETE statemnets supported yet in cstore_ftw Postgres extension?

Tags: database, postgresql

I would love to use this extension for columnar storage. However, I need the ability to DELETE and UPDATE. On their repo https://github.com/citusdata/cstore_fdw
I could find two very old issues on this, one closed and one still open. They said in 2014 it is on their roadmap but I could not find any updates or if it is supporting this now.

Is it supported yet or in active development?

Answer (score 0):

According to the source code, it allows `INSERT`, but not `UPDATE`, `DELETE` or `TRUNCATE`.